# grep command hogs the whole cpu

Tags: linux, grep, find

I'm trying to find all files from a folder that contain a certain string. Unfortunately it looks like I'm doing something wrong because this hogs the entire CPU. I'm running Ubuntu. Can somebody please advise?

This is the command I run: find /var/logs/ -xdev -type f | xargs grep -i "ID59103"

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13944 root      20   0  101m 1128  720 R 100.0  0.0   9:26.37 grep
 2793 root      20   0  523m 128m 1012 S  2.7  0.8   8259:23 sw-collectd
   98 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:04.19 kswapd0
```

The directory /var/logs/ has about 130k files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find all files from a folder that contain a certain string.

Read carefully [grep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) and try to run `grep --help`.

You could want to run

```
grep -rn ID59103 /var/logs/
```

BTW `/var/logs/` might be a typo. Perhaps you want `/var/log/` ?

Read also the documentation of [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) and of [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) and of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

All of these are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You are allowed to download their source code, study that source code and improve each of them to suite your needs.

> The directory /var/logs/ has about 130k files.

In practice, `grep` is often taking advantage of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) so could be CPU intensive. For an explanation, see [Linux Ate My RAM](http://linuxatemyram.com/).

Comment: After reading the manuals like 5 times I got it in the end. Thanks. This can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. No, it is not a typo, as I'm not trying to look into /var/log/ logs but in some old logs which I put in /var/logs/.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that there are about 130k files in that directory (I will update this info in the question).

The command you gave me seems to be working better, but is still using 70% of the CPU.

Comment: Why does that 70% figure surprises you? Most of the data is in RAM, and then `grep` is CPU bound. See http://linuxatemyram.com/